# Call Release and play multiple sound

Tags: android, audio, mp3, release

with this code I want to stop all the sounds that are being executed, and play only the button clicked, but calling the release, the sound becomes null and you can not run the sound again. but if you do not call release give me problem anyway. how can I find a solution to this conundrum?

Code:

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    public Boolean playing = false;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

               public void onClick(View v){



                   if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();









                   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(menu.this, R.raw.b1);
                   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            mediaPlayer.start();

                            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    mediaPlayer.release();
                                    playing=true;
                                };
                            });

                                }
                            });


Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

               public void onClick(View v){


                   if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();

                   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b2);
                   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            mediaPlayer.start();

                            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    mediaPlayer.release();

                                };
                            });
                                }
                            });

               }});
```

Comment: try using `reset()` instead of release

Comment: and you tried using `stop()` as well right?

Comment: why not use stop in the `onCompletion` listner?

Comment: yes try using it without the release to see if that will help you

Comment: Give me an example of code so I can also accept your answer if you helped me

Comment: `mediaPlayer.stop(); mediaPlayer.release();` try this and see if it works.

Comment: no returns null the sound if I press the button a second time gives me the problem

Comment: is confusing mediaplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by this:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

               public void onClick(View v){



                   if(mediaPlayer!=null&&mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                       mediaPlayer.stop();
                       mediaPlayer.release();
                     }









                   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(menu.this, R.raw.b1);
                   mediaPlayer.start();

                }});
```